# DataGrid columns doesn't resize properly

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I'm using a `DataGrid` in my WPF application to display some data. Upon application load, sometimes the Grid's columns get weird and the left "Select All" button disappears, causing the columns dividers not to be exactly where the column is. Only when the user tries to resize the column the Grids' layout becomes OK.

My DataGrid definition is:
`<DataGrid Name="myList" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource ="{Binding SortedView}" VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="False" ColumnWidth="Auto">`

Here is a screenshot of the problem for illustration:

[image: The bad layout of my DataGrid]

Here's the full XAML code for the DataGrid:

```
<DataGrid Name="myList" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource ="{Binding SortedView}" VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="False" ColumnWidth="Auto">
        <Interactivity:Interaction.Triggers>
            <Interactivity:EventTrigger EventName="Sorting" >
                <WPFCommon:InvokeDelegateCommandAction 
                            Command="{Binding SortCommand}"
                            CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=InvokeParameter}" />
            </Interactivity:EventTrigger>
        </Interactivity:Interaction.Triggers>
        <DataGrid.RowStyle>
            <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
                <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding Mode=TwoWay, Path=IsSelected}"/>
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.RowStyle>
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="{x:Static p:Resources.Sensor}" Binding="{Binding SensorName, Mode=OneWay}" Width="Auto" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="{x:Static p:Resources.Status}" CanUserSort="True" Binding="{Binding Classification, Mode=OneWay}" Width="Auto" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="{x:Static p:Resources.Created}" Binding="{Binding CreatedDate, Mode=OneWay}" CanUserSort="True" Width="Auto" IsReadOnly="True" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="{x:Static p:Resources.Last_Updated}" Binding="{Binding LastUpdated, Mode=OneWay}" CanUserSort="True" Width="*" IsReadOnly="True" />
        </DataGrid.Columns >
    </DataGrid>
```

If anyone has an idea of how to get the `DataGrid` to automatically resize or refresh upon load / change it would be great.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you please show the xaml of your datagrid and also what is the Width of DataGrid.

Comment: I added the full XAML code of my DataGrid, thanks!

Comment: I think it has to do with the Horizontal scrollbar...

Comment: set the MinWidth of DataGrid atleast the columns fits in it or set HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto".

Comment: Thanks ethicallogics, but that didn't work...

Comment: I added `HeadersVisibility="Column"` to the `DataGrid` definition. It's a simple quickfix and it does the trick.